# AngularJS implement $q

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

```
( function() {
  angular.module('foo')

  .factory('someFac', function ($injector, $http, $q){
      var temp;
      $http.get('url').then(function(response){ //implement $q to wait for this to finish
           if(response === 1){
               temp = 1
           else{
               temp = 2
      });
     return $injector.get(temp); 
}());
```

How could I implement $q to make the promise resolve before returning?

Comment: you don't need `$q` here because `$http` already returns a promise, but in this case your code is in the `then` block, which means it ***already*** is waiting for the call to finish. What is the **real** problem you are having?

Comment: Well the program is suppose to get information from the URL using $http.get, but it is returning before the promise is done causing an error, and I can't edit where it is being called from because it is being called directly from the AngularJS code.

Comment: just making a guess here based on what this code seems to be trying to do, your `return` isn't waiting for the promise to finish, because the entire purpose of a promise is to allow the execution to continue.  You *probably* want to put the return inside the `then` callback.

Comment: You can't wait. Forget about waiting. What you can do is return the $http promise, and call then() in the calling code.  Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: I think that your code flow is showing that you are misunderstanding the way that promises work.  you are already waiting for the promise to complete before **assigning a value** to `temp`, but you are attempting to make another call that relies upon that value immediately.

Comment: Okay, so is there another practice that would be a better solution for my problem?

Comment: if you must return the `$injector` here, then move the return into the `.then` block, and don't even assign a `temp` value.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution Claies, and I'm getting an error saying that $get factory method must return a value

Comment: I've been doing a bit more research, and I'm not even sure if what you are trying to accomplish here (dynamically choose between two dependencies) is even supported by the angular Dependency Injection.

Comment: Yeah, I've been stuck with this problem for a while now, been trying many solutions, but none of yet to work

Comment: Thank you for your help Claies, me and my team are redesigning how we are going to have our application run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While http does return a promise, you can process the results like you are and use the $q library as such:

```
( function() {
angular.module('foo')

  .factory('someFac', function ($injector, $http, $q){
    var temp;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('url').then(function(response){ //implement $q to wait for this to finish
       if(response === 1){
           deferred.resolve(1);
       else{
           deferred.reject(2);
  });
 return deferred.promise; 
}());
```

You can reject or resolve and pass the necessary data via the defer object.

Answer (score -1):

You add this code in app.js file, You don't need to throw exception from server side, you just add code in exception just like

```
public ActionResult YourMethodName(string emailAddress)
    {
        BasicResponse Response = new BasicResponse();

        try
        {
           // do your work here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.ErrorKey = ex.Message;
            Response.ErrorCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        return Json(Response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It automatically catches in $q service, you can add your desired error code in server code and map here in switch

```
angular.module('foo').factory('responeInterceptor', ['$q', '$window', '$injector', 'NotificationService', function ($q, $window, $injector, notifyService) {
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            // do something on success
            return response;
        },

        //in case of Error
        'responseError': function (rejection) {


            switch (rejection.status) {
                case 400:
                    notifyService.notifyError(rejection.data.errorKey);
                    break;
                case 403:
                    $window.location.href = '/Logout';
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: what does this have to do with the question? was this meant for a different question? this question has nothing to do with exceptions or anything even close to this code.

Comment: I got your point, yes this question nothing to do with exception, but you can also manage exceptions by $q.

Comment: so you're saying that this is still a good answer because it uses the library the question mentions, though it doesn't illustrate anything the OP is trying to do at all?  and in fact, mentions doing something server side, with server code that may or may not be in the language the OP is using?